# Ошибка Service Temporarily Unavailable при Ajax запросе в WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

GET запрос к `admin-ajax.php` в `WordPress` возвращает ошибку Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Пробовал делать и POST, и по другому написать скрипт запроса - не помогло.

Но при этом правильно работало только в Хроме, в остальных браузерах выдает вышеуказанную ошибку. На другом компьютере ошибку выдает в любом браузере, даже в хроме. Сама функция в php работает корректно. Скрипт JS тоже правильный, никаких ошибок не выдает. Ну и все это иногда работает как надо:

после того как я вставляю в адресную строку тот самый GET запрос (вида http://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getElements&id=23), он показывает результат и начинает работать в этом браузере и с сайта. Т.е. ошибка для этого браузера решается полностью, до тех пор пока не очистить кэш.

Если это важно - то Word Press установлен в подпапку. Типа `mysite.com/sites/sitename`

С чем это может быть связано? Может настройки сервера?

Код на всякий случай:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: frontendajax.ajaxurl,
        type: "GET",
        data: {"id": id, "action" : "getCatalogItem"},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
            alert(error); // Тут и показывается Service Temporarily Unavailable 
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
function getCatalogItem(){
    echo 'Text';
}

add_action('wp_ajax_getCatalogItem', 'getCatalogItem'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getCatalogItem', 'getCatalogItem');
```

Comment: Это связано с плохим кодом php.  Service Temporarily Unavailable (503), как и все 500-ошибки, это ошибки  сервера. Ни браузер, ни кеши - ни при чем. Покажите ваш php-код. Но уже сейчас видно, что сделано все не по стандартам WP. Почитайте хорошее руководство о том, как надо делать Ajax в wp: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign добавил код в вопрос. Но повторяю, сам код рабочий.

Comment: Код нерабочий. Выполнен не в соответствии с теми инструкциями, на которые я дал ссылку.

Comment: @KAGGDesign перепроверил все и сделал в точности как в примере. Результат тот же, в хроме работает, в других браузерах и на других устройствах - не работает. Думаю все-таки дело не в коде, а в настройках сервера. Аякс в вордпресе делаю не первый раз.

Comment: Ну ок, не хотите читать инструкции и делать, как правильно - грешите на браузеры, настройки сервера и т.д.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я прочитал инструкцию и сделал все по ней. Если вы видите ошибку, пожалуйста укажите на неё.

Comment: Вы три буквы в инструкции можете заметить? Die. И Кама явно про это пишет. Как же вы читаете?

Comment: @KAGGDesign это тоже добавил. Сделал абсолютно все как в инструкции. Не помогло

Comment: ваш код у меня работает. только заменила `frontendajax.ajaxurl` на `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` и добавила `wp_die();` в конце функции `getCatalogItem()`.

Comment: Проблема решилась сама при переносе сайта из подпапки на в корневую папку сайта.